# what is a group leader

Tags: elixir

I am trying to configure out, what is a group leader and how it is related with I/O module, but could not find anything useful in internet. Can please someone explain me?

I have following scenario from elixir 1.2 book(Dave Thomas):
[image]

On the second window, why does he pass `:erlang_group_leader`? For what it is good for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[From documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#group_leader-0):

> ```
> group_leader() -> pid()
> ```
>
> Returns the process identifier of the group leader for the process evaluating the function.
>
> Every process is a member of some process group and all groups have a group leader. All I/O from the group is channeled to the group leader. When a new process is spawned, it gets the same group leader as the spawning process. Initially, at system start-up, init is both its own group leader and the group leader of all processes.

And:

> ```
> group_leader(GroupLeader, Pid) -> true
> ```
>
> Types:
>
> ```
> GroupLeader = Pid = pid()
> ```
>
> Sets the group leader of Pid to GroupLeader. Typically, this is used when a process started from a certain shell is to have another group leader than init.
>
> ```
> See also group_leader/0.
> ```

There is also some [Elixir-specific documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/io-and-the-file-system.html#processes-and-group-leaders):

> By modelling IO devices with processes, the Erlang VM allows different nodes in the same network to exchange file processes in order to read/write files in between nodes. Of all IO devices, there is one that is special to each process: the group leader.
>
> The group leader can be configured per process and is used in different situations. For example, when executing code in a remote terminal, it guarantees messages in a remote node are redirected and printed in the terminal that triggered the request.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response. What I do not understand is, what is the main task of group leader?

Comment: The main task of the group leader is to collect the I/O output from all the processes in its group and pass that I/O to or from the underlying system.  Basically the group leader owns stdin, stdout, and stderr on behalf of the group and handles passing information to and from channels like those.

Comment: Think about the group leader as a proxy, through which other processes do their IO. So, instead of a group of developers all talking to the accounting department, they appoint a group leader who talks for them (to sort out expenses from the last conference) and they can continue hacking their code.